# How to Validate a Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, validation

I have historical data of a production process, and I've being asked to build a simulation model to predict its performance in the future. Using the historical data, I've being able to obtain the process parameters like the following:

- A probability distribution of the number of work packages
- A probability distribution for the workers productivity

I've also being able to plug those parameters into a Monte Carlo simulation and obtain some predictions. However, so far I'm not sure **how to be sure if my simulation is really reflecting reality**. In machine learning we have cross validation and test-train splits and see how effective the prediction are, and I was wondering if there is a similar approach for simulation models.

**UPDATE:**

- The historical data available correspond to work orders produced from 2003 to 2015.
- Per each work order, we have the lifecycle information: When it was created, every status change and when it was ready for delivery.

Comment: I think the most obvious solution would be to train your simulation leaving out the most recent production period as test data set. It would be nice to have some further information about the time span your data cover (and variables involved etc). Perhaps also a [rolling forecast origin](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/175724/9866) would work but I am not an expert in this topic and for me it is hard to guess without further information.

Comment: @Arne, thanks for the insights. I added some additional information